# app.request.host in symfony/twig behind one (or two) reverse proxies

Tags: php, symfony, proxy, twig

Hie,

I try get a symfony app to work behind to levels of reverse proxy (one for my company, the second one for my departement).

There are many places in the views where app.request.host has been used.
The problem is that this method returns de url of the server symfony is installed on, not the url of the company (nor the virtual path that is used from outside...).

I tried to get a look at the reverse proxy configuration is symfony, but I am not sure I found the right information...

So my questions are :
-is there way to configure my symfony so that app.request.host returns "mycomp.com" rather than "192.168.1.1" ...
- do I need some more stuff to also get the virtual path (eg "mycomp.com/mysymfonyapp") ? should app.request.requestUri do the trick ?

Thanks for help

Matthieu

Comment: In php, does $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] return 'mycomp.com' ?

Comment: No it doesn't...
It returns the ip of the real host...